# How to access file names on client-side in an App written in HTML5?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iphone, html

WHAT I HAVE:

This is my first project ever. It's a vocabulary learning game, and I'm writing it in HTML5/javascript/JQuery and hoping to package it into a phone app.

I have a folder entitled 'vocab' that has files containing wordsets: mandarin_months, mandarin_colors, etc. The files are .js, which I could change later, it was just the easiest way to format the data it at the moment.

This folder will be packaged and on the user's phone.

*

WHAT I NEED:

Now, I want to be able to dynamically populate the first page with buttons to use each of these wordsets in the game. So there'd be a 'months' button, a 'colors' button, etc.

So I need to read:
1. How many files there are in the folder 'vocab', which will be on the client's phone.
2. The names of these files.
X. I don't need to write or read anything from the files themselves.

*

I've looked around a bit. Can I use PHP? ActiveX? Just need a pointer where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean it will be outside your applications directory ? Otherwise if you have jQuery you could just do 

`$.get("folder/vocabulary.js", function(response) { 
  // response contains your vocab 
}, "JSON");` -- read about JSON if you're not familiar yet.

Comment: Just read about JSON. If I put all the different vocab arrays into one .js file that would solve the problem. However, right now I have them in different files. So I need a way to use $.get or something like it without knowing the file name. Just go into "folder/" and get the file names, and run that for how many files there are in "folder/"... In the end I'll just put them all in one file if I can't figure out this solution.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](http://json.org/) data saved as a javascript file  is the best way to do this. It's fast, flexible and you can swap datasets easily. It supports `name, value` pairs in a flat or tree structure and is a good tool for storing and representing language library data.